# angular.bootstrap not working on document ready

Tags: jquery, angularjs

I have a problem inserting angular.bootstap in my partial view. Angular.bootstrap is for some reason not working. I check my javascript error console, but it doesnot show any error! When i copy past my code in the main view, it works. After adding document.ready it doesnot work anymore, but i have no clue why? My code

```
<!doctype html>
<!--[if IE 9]><html class="lt-ie10" lang="en" > <![endif]-->
<html lang="en-US" ng-app="app">
<head>
<meta charset="utf-8"/>
<meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0"/>
<meta name="csrf-param" content="_csrf">
<meta name="csrf-token"  content="bXRXLUhDZmFVAQRkDBQSABozZQB.IAAIBUECVyUFN1A5RjhpFw5TNA==">
  <title>mytest</title>
<script type='text/javascript' src="/themes/admin/js/jquery.js"></script>
<link href="/foundation/css/foundation.css" rel="stylesheet" />
<script src="/assets/cca10116/angular/angular.js"></script>
<script src="/assets/cca10116/angular-route/angular-route.js"></script>
<script src="/assets/cca10116/angular-strap/dist/angular-strap.js"></script>
<script>paceOptions = {ajax: {trackMethods: ['GET', 'POST']}};</script>
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/pace/1.0.2/pace.js">      </script>

 <link   href="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/pace/1.0.2/themes/red/pace-theme-minimal.css" rel="stylesheet" />
<meta name="description" content="For documentation we advice you to contact us on www.sriservices.nl"/>
<meta name="author" content="ttt"/>
<meta name="copyright" content="ttt"/>
 <script src="/foundation/js/vendor/modernizr.js"></script>
 </head>
 <body >

  <div id='wrapper'>

        <nav class="top-bar" data-topbar>
        <ul class="title-area">
                <li class="name">
                <h1>
                <a href="/#/" data-match-route="/$">
                SRIservices Mexico Advance Framework
                </a>
                </h1>
                </li>
                <li class="toggle-topbar menu-icon"><a href="#">  <span>menu</span></a></li>
        </ul>
            <section class="top-bar-section">
                    <ul class="right">
                            <li class="divider"></li>
                            <li data-match-route="/$"><a href="/#/">Home</a></li>
                            <li class="divider"></li>
                            <li data-match-route="/about"><a href="/#/about">About</a></li>
                            <li class="divider"></li>
                            <li data-match-route="contact"><a href="/#/contact">Contact</a></li>
                            <li class="divider"></li>
                            <li onclick='$("body").html("");location.reload(true);'><a href="/login">Login</a></li>
                            <li class="divider"></li>
                    </ul>
            </section>
        </nav>


        <div ng-view></div>


   </div>
        <div class='container footer'>
             <div class='row footer-content'>
                     The advance framework "for all your software" is   
             </div>
        </div>


     <script src="/js/app.js"></script>
     <script src="/js/angular-css.min.js"></script>       

     <script>
    document.write('<script src=js/vendor/' +
    ('__proto__' in {} ? 'zepto' : 'jquery') +
    '.js><\/script>')
    </script>
    <script src="/foundation/js/foundation.min.js"></script>
    <script>
      $(document).foundation();
    </script>
<div class='container'>
<div class="row">
     <div class="large-8 columns" id='form'>
     <h1>Contact</h1>


     <p>
            If you have business inquiries or other questions, please fill out the following form to contact us. Thank you.
     </p>


    <form id="contact-form" action=""  method="post" role="form" ng-controller="validateCtrl" name="myForm" novalidate>
    <label class="control-label" for="contactform-name">Name</label>

    <input type="text" id="contactform-name" class="form-control" name="name" ng-model="name" required>

      <span style="color:red" ng-show="myForm.name.$dirty && myForm.name.$invalid">
      <span ng-show="myForm.name.$error.required">Name is required.</span>
      </span>


    <label class="control-label" for="contactform-email">Email</label>

    <input type="text" id="contactform-email" class="form-control" name="email" ng-model="email" required>
    <span style="color:red" ng-show="myForm.email.$dirty && myForm.email.$invalid">
    <span ng-show="myForm.email.$error.required">Email is required.</span>
    <span ng-show="myForm.email.$error.email">Invalid email address.</span>
    </span>     

    <label class="control-label" for="contactform-subject">Subject</label>

    <input type="text" id="contactform-subject" class="form-control" name="subject" ng-model="subject" required>
    <span style="color:red" ng-show="myForm.subject.$dirty && myForm.subject.$invalid">
    <span ng-show="myForm.subject.$error.required">Subject is required.</span>
    </span>     

    <label class="control-label" for="contactform-body" ng-model="body" required>Body</label>

    <textarea id="contactform-body" class="form-control" name="body" rows="6" ng-model="body" required></textarea>
    <span style="color:red" ng-show="myForm.body.$dirty && myForm.body.$invalid">
    <span ng-show="myForm.body.$error.required">Body is required.</span>
    </span>

     <br style='clear:both;' />
     <button type="submit" class="btn btn-primary" name="contact-button" ng-disabled="myForm.user.$dirty && myForm.user.$invalid || myForm.email.$dirty && myForm.email.$invalid">Submit</button>                

     </form>        
     </div>
</div>
</div>

  <script>

var app1 = angular.module('myApp', []);

app1.controller('validateCtrl', function($scope) {
$scope.name = 'John Doe';
$scope.email = 'john.doe@gmail.com';
});

 $( document ).ready(function() {
angular.bootstrap(document.getElementById('contact-form'), ['myApp']);
});

</script>
</body>
</html>
```

so far my app.js looks like:

```
 //https://oclazyload.readme.io/docs
var app = angular.module('app', [
'ngRoute',      //$routeProvider
'mgcrea.ngStrap', //bs-navbar, data-match-route directives
'door3.css',
 ]);



app.config(['$routeProvider','$locationProvider',
function($routeProvider, $locationProvider) {
$routeProvider.
    when('/', {
        templateUrl: 'views/partials/index.html',

    }).
    when('/about', {
        templateUrl: 'views/partials/about.html',
    }).
    when('/contact', {
         templateUrl: 'views/partials/contact.html',
    }).
    when('/login', {

        templateUrl: 'themes/admin/views/admin/partials/login.html'

    }).
    otherwise({
        templateUrl: 'views/partials/index.html',
    });




//check browser support
if(window.history && window.history.pushState){
    //$locationProvider.html5Mode(true); will cause an error $location in HTML5 mode requires a  tag to be present! Unless you set baseUrl tag after head tag like so: <head> <base href="/">

 // to know more about setting base URL visit: https://docs.angularjs.org/error/$location/nobase

 // if you don't wish to set base URL then use this
 $locationProvider.html5Mode({
         enabled: true,
         requireBase: false
  });
}
}]);
```

Comment: so far my app.js looks like:

Comment: mismatch between module name in bootstrap and in actual module. Wouldn't you want to include more of the page like initialize on `wrapper` maybe?

Comment: Not sure i understand you, could you explain a little bit more, i just started with angular.

Comment: `module('app',[])` ...`angular.bootstrap(document.getElementById('contact-form'), ['myApp']);`  these are not the same  `app` !==`myApp`. Might want to just use `ng-app` in markup. Is more common way to initalize

Comment: Well even if i do this, it doesnot work: app.controller('validateCtrl', function($scope) {
    $scope.name = 'John Doe';
    $scope.email = 'john.doe@gmail.com';
});

$( document ).ready(function() {
angular.bootstrap(document.getElementById('contact-form'), ['app']);
});

Comment: What i am trying to do is make 2 apps in 1 view

Comment: If you are new that is probably a bad idea. There are lots of ways to have multiple nested views in one app

Comment: And try to familiarize with this https://github.com/johnpapa/angular-styleguide/blob/master/README.md It will help you save a lot of time